# Error writing to file ascii.enc while installing python 2.7.11 on windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, npm-install

I am installing npm using command "npm install -g windows-build-tools from an elevated PowerShell (run as Administrator)". It has few dependencies of visual c
++ tools and python 2.7
I am receiving an error while installing python 2.7.11 
While installing by admin also i am receiving error.
I have tried giving permissions to that specific location also, set UAC to never notify also. but nothing works.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zJSY.png)

Answer (score 1):

I know it probably late but thought I'd add my thoughts.

Its most likely due to your anti-virus access protection denying write permission for this extension. I had the exact same trouble while trying to install both Python 2 and 3 but it worked fine when I temporarily paused my anti-virus.

.enc extension is associated with ransom wares and therefore most organizations black lists this particular file.

You can try rename any text file to .enc and would notice the same error.